# Do I need to attribute icons not used anymore but visible on GitHub's previous commits?

Tags: licensing

I'm developing a mobile app and I'm using GitHub for source code which is set to public, so I can show my friends.

I was using some free icons from www.flaticon.com/home , which required the developer to attribute the authors to the icons.

But I decided to go ahead and just create my own icons and delete all the icons I was using the flaticon, but the problem is in the previous commits on GitHub, the old images of the icons are still visible in my resource folders.

Is this a problem I need to address at all? Do I need to mention anywhere that I WAS using icons from FlatIcon or am I good to just act like it never happened?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but I think if the commit that used the icons had attribution somewhere that would be fine, and it should be able to be removed with the commit that removed the icons. As long as the attribution existed at that point in time, you were compliant.

Comment: Hmm I was just planning on adding the attribution page at the end, when I'm finished my app, I didn't expect to change my mind and create my own icons. So the attribution on the page wasn't there.. Would it be okay if in the commit where I remove all the icons I used I just add an attribution mentioning the use of them before I stopped using them? @RonBeyer

Comment: That I'm not too sure about (and you may want to ask on [OpenSource.SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/).